# ul/li bullet points disappearing in Chrome with Typekit

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, typekit

I appear to have a rather strange bug in Chrome Version 46.0.2490.71 (64-bit) on Linux, only applying to a specific site I'm building. Any list elements like `<ul>` and `<ol>` have their items displayed without any bullets. If I change the element's rendering in any way - like selecting it with the mouse - the bullet points return, but this has to be done after every page load.

I've disabled all my custom CSS/Sass and could confirm that the problem kept happening. Disabling JavaScript fixed the issue, at the cost of also removing my custom font. I am importing Futura PT to the page via TypeKit, which means that a JavaScript snippet loads the custom font post-loading. Without it, the list shows up fine.

I am convinced that this is a bug since the bullets reappear if you change the list CSS in Developer Tools, or simply drag-select the items. However, I wonder if there is some kind of workaround.

The lists themselves are rather ordinary:

```
<ul>
  <li>List level 1</li>
  <li>List level 1
    <ul>
      <li>List level 2</li>
      <li>List level 2
        <ul>
          <li>List level 3</li>
          <li>List level 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is a series of screenshots detailing the problem.

> 1) JavaScript disabled: no TypeKit. List loads fine.

[image: JavaScript disabled: no TypeKit. List loads fine.]

> 2) JavaScript enabled: TypeKit kicks in. List has no bullets.

[image: JavaScript enabled: TypeKit kicks in. List has no bullets.]

> 3) Selecting a few list items reveals bullets for those items only.

[image: Selecting a few list items reveals bullets for those items only.]

> 4) Same as above, after the selection.

[image: Same as above, after the selection.]

Comment: Provide a code snippet that produces your problem please

Comment: Code is rather pointless here, as it's just a simple HTML list and CSS does not influence the issue, but I've provided helpful screenshots.

Comment: I'm assuming you set the list-style-type to none and it's still showing up. Is that correct? Sorry for not catching your question all the way. Do you want bullets or not want bullets?

Comment: I want the list bullets to display; they just don't if TypeKit is enabled. List-styles have ranged from standard browser, to square/decimal. I just confirmed that they disappear even if TypeKit doesn't actually load a font, too.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll see what I can find out.

Comment: Are you using any OpenType features?

Comment: Sadly I'm using our client's Typekit ID, so I couldn't tell. It's simply adding the font Futura PT in regular and bold versions. I'll forward the question to the client.

Comment: @TysonGraham Yes, all OpenType features are supported, also all characters.